# Is it possible to get parameter from flatMap?

Tags: java, java-stream

Is it possible to get parameter from flatMap?

```
list.stream().flatMap(a -> a.getBs().stream()).forEach(b->System.out.print(a));
```

I can't access `a` from `b`

Comment: What do you mean `accept a from b` ? Anyway once you've flatMapped your stream, its original data is lost, being replaced by the result of your mapping. How about `list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(a, a.getBs())` (or another way to map "A"s to "B"s, using a `Stream` here seems wasteful) which would produce a `Map<A,B>` from which you could access (from a Stream if you want) both "A"s and "B"s ?

Comment: The flatmap in your example returns you all the Bs. Tehrefore only the Bs are availiable in your foreach. A is not accessible.

Comment: Why do you need to flatmap to bs in the first place? In other words, why do you need a stream of `b`s, while also need to preserve the `a`s from which each `b` came from? I think I'm asking more information, so that we can be of more help.

Comment: By regular looping I can access outer object, but I want to replace loops with lambda expression, so I need the way to do it.

Comment: You can use lambdas without using a stream (although I doubt you'll find it very useful). The problem I'm sure is that your loop uses its scope context to retain the reference to the A, which is not something you do in functional programming (which streams implement).

Comment: Also note that `.forEach` is a terminal operation : it consumes the Stream and doesn't return it. Even if you were able to use a stream to 1) map As to Bs and then 2) print As, you then wouldn't be able to 3) work on Bs. Maybe you would like to use something along the lines of `list.stream().peek(System.out::println).flatMap(a-> a.gestBs().stream()).somethingElseWithBs` (but at this point I think you should tell us what your algorithm is or even post your current working loop)

Answer (score 2):

You can't access variables of previous `lambdas` because they are out of scope. Lambda is just an anonymous class.
Your lambda `a -> a.getBs().stream())` can be written as this

```
list.stream().flatMap(new Function<YourClass, Stream<?>>() {
        @Override
        public Stream<?> apply(YourClass foo) {
            return foo.getBs().stream();
        }
    });
```

Your `a` variable from lamba is `foo` in the anonymous class. It's just a function parameter and it's only visible inside the `apply` function.